# redirect a mobile site only once

Tags: html, redirect, mobile

Hy i just want to know the code to paste to the "index.html" of my website so i Can ask Mobiles users if they want to be redirected to mobile version or go to desktop version
but i haven't figured out a way
Cause the code i found always redirect with no chance to go to desktop version on mobile

I am not able to post the code that i found but the question says it all

If this is not possible i just want to know a code that redirect mobile users only "ONCE" please and thank you

i have no professional experience in this...just a beginner

Comment: http://www.ezmobilewebsitetools.com/howto-redirect.html

Comment: @jonhopkins that link is almost perfect for him, might want to suggest it as an answer.

Comment: @jonhopkins Does the code you provided redirect only once? and do i have to change the mobile/ to my mobile website?

Comment: @gs2rom I'm not sure. I just found it because your question made me want to do the same thing. I'm looking at it now to figure out if it does or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the instructions at http://www.ezmobilewebsitetools.com/howto-redirect.html:

Paste the following code in the `<head>` section of your index.html

```
<script>
if ((document.location.hostname.match(/\.mobi$/) || screen.width < 699)
    && (document.cookie.indexOf("skipmobile") == -1 || getCookie("skipmobile") == -1)
{
    document.location = "mobile/"; //change this to location of your mobile site
} else if (document.location.search.indexOf("skipmobile") >= 0) {
    document.cookie = "skipmobile=1";
}

//getCookie function from http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp
function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++) {
        x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
        x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
        if (x==c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

This will detect if a user is on a device with a screen width of less than 699 pixels, or if they have gone to the .mobi domain of your site (if you have one). To allow the user to go back to the desktop site, create a link somewhere on your mobile page

```
<a href="http://www.MyWebsite.com/?skipmobile=1">
```

This will create a cookie notifying the site to go stay on the desktop site for that user. Based on the same logic, I believe putting the following link on the desktop site will change this cookie to allow the user to go back to the mobile site.

```
<a href="http://www.MyWebsite.com/?skipmobile=-1">
```

Note that I do not know much about cookies and have not tested this. If someone with more knowledge can verify, or correct, the second link, I would appreciate it, and I'm sure gs2rom would as well.

Comment: Do i have to change <a href="http://www.MyWebsite.com/?skipmobile=1"> with my desktop version and the <a href="http://www.MyWebsite.com/?skipmobile=-1"> with my Mobile version?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cookies. For exemple, set a Cookie when the user selects "desktop version", an when the user comes back check if it exists or not.

How to set a Cookie in PHP [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp) (http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp)